# Long running thread in WinDbg

Tags: asp.net, windbg

I have a thread (#39) that has been running for quite some time and trying to figure out why using windbg. The last instruction on the stack is NtRemoveIoCompletion. The application is ASP.Net 4.8. The application has been running 6 minutes when the dump was created. I am thinking this is some kind of low level completion port thread and perhaps can safely ignore it?

```
0:079> !runaway
 User Mode Time
  Thread       Time
   39:3898     0 days 0:00:37.859
   26:3314     0 days 0:00:07.859
   21:1030     0 days 0:00:04.921
   23:2f10     0 days 0:00:04.859
   24:4c9c     0 days 0:00:04.781
   20:2798     0 days 0:00:04.656
   11:4754     0 days 0:00:04.546
   10:3238     0 days 0:00:04.390
   27:48fc     0 days 0:00:04.328
   25:3248     0 days 0:00:04.328
   22:4434     0 days 0:00:04.140
   60:1d90     0 days 0:00:00.406

0:039> !threads
ThreadCount:      47
UnstartedThread:  0
BackgroundThread: 40
PendingThread:    0
DeadThread:       3
Hosted Runtime:   no
                                                                                                        Lock  
       ID OSID ThreadOBJ           State GC Mode     GC Alloc Context                  Domain           Count Apt Exception
  11    1 4754 000000b2ee860f00    28220 Preemptive  000000B47A3EE318:000000B47A3EEFD0 000000b2ee85fec0 0     Ukn 
  28    2 398c 000000b2ee9ea0d0    2b220 Preemptive  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 000000b2ee85fec0 0     MTA (Finalizer) 
  30    3 4f28 000000b77a8bd970  102a220 Preemptive  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 000000b2ee85fec0 0     MTA (Threadpool Worker) 
  31    4 24a8 000000b77a8c7730    21220 Preemptive  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 000000b2ee85fec0 0     Ukn 
  33    6 4168 000000b77a9f9ec0  1020220 Preemptive  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 000000b2ee85fec0 0     Ukn (Threadpool Worker) 
  34    9   78 000000b77aa86e20  a029220 Preemptive  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 000000b77a8c66f0 0     MTA (Threadpool Completion Port) 
  35   10 44c0 000000b780a25150  202b020 Preemptive  000000B2F9661810:000000B2F9661FD0 000000b77a8c66f0 0     MTA 
  37   11 32d4 000000b780b925f0  202b020 Preemptive  000000B67CBF01A8:000000B67CBF1FD0 000000b77a8c66f0 0     MTA 
  38   12 1be0 000000b780b994b0  1029220 Preemptive  000000B3FA010F90:000000B3FA011FD0 000000b2ee85fec0 0     MTA (Threadpool Worker) 
  39   14 3898 000000b780c14110  8029220 Preemptive  000000B67CBDA3F0:000000B67CBDC000 000000b2ee85fec0 0     MTA (Threadpool Completion Port) 
   2   19 3188 000000b780bd05d0    20220 Preemptive  000000B2F96522F8:000000B2F9653FD0 000000b2ee85fec0 0     Ukn 
  40   20 2f00 000000b780bd0da0  202b220 Preemptive  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 000000b77a8c66f0 0     MTA 
  45   21 1b30 000000b780daeb60  1029220 Preemptive  000000B2F964EB60:000000B2F964FFD0 000000b2ee85fec0 0     MTA (Threadpool Worker) 
  46   22 38d8 000000b780dae390  1029220 Preemptive  000000B37C4C92A0:000000B37C4C9FD0 000000b2ee85fec0 0     MTA (Threadpool Worker) 
  47   23 40c8 000000b780dac450  1029220 Preemptive  000000B47A3E4C88:000000B47A3E4FD0 000000b2ee85fec0 0     MTA (Threadpool Worker) 
[...]

0:039> kb
 # RetAddr           : Args to Child                                                           : Call Site
00 00007ffe`77d04943 : 000000b7`80c14110 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000001 000000b7`7aa6bb50 : ntdll!NtRemoveIoCompletion+0xa
01 00007ffe`722aea3c : 00000000`00003a98 000000b7`82fcf6c0 00000000`80010000 000000b7`80c14110 : KERNELBASE!GetQueuedCompletionStatus+0x3f
02 00007ffe`7219c1cf : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000001 00007ffe`0000000c : clr!ThreadpoolMgr::CompletionPortThreadStart+0x210
03 00007ffe`79ed13d2 : 00007ffe`7219c150 000000b7`80bc2610 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : clr!Thread::intermediateThreadProc+0x86
04 00007ffe`7a7a54f4 : 00007ffe`79ed13b0 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0x22
05 00000000`00000000 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart+0x34
```

Answer (score 0):

It's look like something is waiting to io completion port. 
Please print all the native stacks. 
~*k => command

and the cpu usage of your machine, 
!threadpool   (with sos.dll extension)

My guess it's you have hang (low cpu) and you wait in the other threads as well